# No rows or columns when binding a DataGrid to a DataTable

Tags: wpf, datatable, datagrid

I am trying to show the contents of a SQL Server table in a `DataGrid`.  I've reduced it to the most basic version and am leaving everything default, and am not seeing any column headings nor any rows.

Here is my code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Test1DataSet test1DataSet = new Test1DataSet();
        Test1DataSetTableAdapters.AdminUserTableAdapter tableAdapter =
            new Test1DataSetTableAdapters.AdminUserTableAdapter();
        tableAdapter.Fill(test1DataSet.AdminUser);

       Test1DataSet.AdminUserDataTable dataTable = tableAdapter.GetData();
        Console.WriteLine(dataTable.Count);

        dataGrid.DataContext = dataTable.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml:

```
<Grid Name="Grid1">
    <DataGrid Margin="25" Name="dataGrid">
      <!--  <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding id}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns> -->
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Table definition:
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdminUser] (
[id]             INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[EmployeeNumber] NVARCHAR (30)  NOT NULL,
[FirstName]      NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
[LastName]       NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
[isSA]           BIT            NOT NULL,
[isDA]           BIT            NOT NULL
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FramworkElement.DataContext` property is meant to serve as context for data binding. It allows to define source agnostic bindings that can be reused when the data source changes.
[Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-5.0)

When you want to show data in a `ItemsControl` you must always assign a data source to the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property (and not to the `FrameworkElement.DataContext`).

Assign the data source using data binding (and `DataContext`):

```cs
class MainWindow : Window
{
  public DataTable TableData { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    // Set DataContext for data binding,
    // where this MainWindow instance will implicitly serve as the data source.
    this.DataContext = this
  }
}
```

```xml
<Window>
  
  <!-- DataGrid inherits the DataContext of its parent (MainWindow) implicitly -->
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TableData}" />
</Window>
```

Or if you don't use data binding:

```cs
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = this.TableData.DefaultView;
```